# Mysqli - Correct parameter for date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

When using prepared statements in MySQLi, and inserting a date into a MySQL database, what parameter should i then use?

Example code:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
$date = date("Y-m-d")
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (date) VALUE (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("WHAT PARAMETER TO USE?", $date); // <--- What parameter?
$stnt->execute();
$stmt->close();
?>
```

**Summary:**

When inserting into MySQL database with MySQLI (Row type is 'date'), what parameter is the correct to use with the `bind_param` when using prepared statements? Is it just 's' for string, or...?

If i made some bad  code above, i would be happy to know. I'm new to MySQLi, and it would be nice to know what i made wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to insert the current date or current time its easier to just use the MySQL function like this: `INSERT INTO table (date) VALUE (NOW())`

Comment: Actually i am aware of that. But it's not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "s" this could be used for date, datetime.
Its treated as just any other string.

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', $date);
```

Answer (score -1):

What's 'date' type? Is it an integer or a string?

If it's a string, use *s*.

If it's a integer, which only have numbers, use *i*.

But, in this case `date('Y-m-d');` will output as: `2014-03-16`, you better use string. Because it have '-'.